# CakePHP validation errors

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm trying to validate an input with CakePHP 2.3.8. When the input passes the validation it works fine. However, when it doesn't meet the validation requirements I get the following error

```
Warning (2): vsprintf(): Too few arguments [CORE/Cake/basics.php, line 619]
```

This displays at the top. Around the input where the message should be displayed, it's just a blank red outline, like the message wasn't passed.

Here's my validation

```
'sales_tax' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('confirm_percentage'),
            'message' => 'Sales tax must be a percentage (Ex: 4.005%)'
        )
),
```

I also tried this without the 'valid' array and the error still persists. And the function

```
function confirm_percentage($value){
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9]/', $value['sales_tax'])){ //just checking if input starts with number for testing purposes
        return true; //no error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately your validation rule message is being passed to `vsprintf()` (in `__d()`), and so it must be formatted to be [**`sprintf`**](http://php.net/sprintf) compatible.

The problem is that you are passing an `%`, which is the conversion specifier identificator, and so `vsprintf()` expects you to pass additional arguments appropriately.

Long story short, escape the `%` with another `%`:

```
'message' => 'Sales tax must be a percentage (Ex: 4.005%%)'
```